# Matching inflation

Tags: matching, case-control-study, observational-study, medicine

I have data on a few millions of patients, about 1000 of them are cases, that is, they were diagnosed having a certain disease at some timepoint in their life.

I think I basically have two options:
1) match to each case a number of controls (e.g. based on age at diagnosis, gender, etc.)
2) Use all the non-cases as a control cohort.

However, someone came with a different proposal:
Take all the individuals that can be matched to each case, and pool them together. Since many of the non-cases can be matched to more than one case patient, this will result with a large data set that will containn much more observations than the original data set (in my case, about 4 times larger). This is beecause many of the non-cases are included in the final data set more than once.
More over, since one of the proposed matching variables was age at diagnosis, it was argued that a patient who was diagnosed at age 26, for example, can serve as a control for a patient who was diagnosed at age 25.

I cannot find any justification to this approach, but on the other hand I was not able to provide convincing arguments (not that I do not have such arguments, only that the person with that suggestion was not convinced).

My question is if there is any good justification for this inflation of the control cohort.

Comment: There is no reason why the control and treatment cohort should be of equal size. More importantly, do not discard perfectly valid control sample light-heartedly. Use a flexible statistical  framework (e.g. generalised additive models) and control for differences due to confounding directly.